# dynamics crm api create quote without opportunity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

First post so apologies if this is a silly question.

I'm interacting with a Dynamics 365 API endpoint from a WEBAPI and need to create a Quote programmatically.

Silly question is am I able to create a straight quote or do I need to create an opportunity first and then the quote from that?

Any help much appreciated

Andy

Comment: Is an opportunity a necessary piece of information to create a quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create opportunity first.